# JFrame showing a huge white box

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jpanel, border-layout

I've been working on a GUI for a project, and so far, I can't seem to get the JFrame to show up at all.  Here's my code.

```
package code;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {
    private JPanel ui, board, u1, u2, game, main;
    private JTextField console;
    private int x, y;

    public GUI (Controller c) {
        setSize(new Dimension(900,710));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //console.setText("Hello, and welcome to the game of Lotus!");
        main = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        game = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        board = new BoardPanel(c);
        ui = new JPanel (new GridLayout(1,2));;
        u1 = new JPanel (new FlowLayout());
        u2 = new StackPanel(c);
        board = new JPanel();

        createAndShowGUI();
        add(main);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public GUI () {
        setSize(new Dimension(900,710));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //console.setText("Hello, and welcome to the game of Lotus!");
        main = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        game = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        board = new BoardPanel();
        ui = new JPanel (new GridLayout(1,2));;
        u1 = new JPanel (new FlowLayout());
        u2 = new StackPanel();
        board = new JPanel();


        createAndShowGUI();
        add(main);
        setVisible(true);
        printToConsole("Yes, it's working!");
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        //add components to ui
        u1.setSize(200,300);
        u2.setSize(200,400);
        ui.add(u1);
        ui.add(u2);

        //add components to game
        board.setSize(700,700);
        ui.setSize(200,700);
        game.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        game.add(ui, BorderLayout.EAST);


        //add main frame components to gui
        main.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        main.add(console, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public void update () {
        repaint();
    }

    public void printToConsole (String s) {
        console.setText(s);
    }

}
```

Whenever I run this, I get a NullPointerException at

> main.add(console, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

If I comment out that line, it runs with no errors, but all that shows up is a huge blank white box.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized `console` which is throwing NullPointerException

```
 console = new JTextField("Some Name");
```

Comment: Don't feel bad. It happens to all of us to initialize instance. Next time give attention to exception, Exception give you much information about error.

Answer (score 0):

The `console` is not instantiated anywhere. Other than that all you have are `JPanel`s, so there is nothing to be displayed as a `JPanel` by itself doesn't offer much visual feedback.